# How to reinitialise swank?

Tags: vim, common-lisp, swank, slimv

How can I make swank forget all previously evaluated definitions?

I want it to undefine all macros, functions, and variables that where defined via evaluations (such as `,b` evaluate buffer).  And have it returned to the same state as when I reboot my PC and freshly start the swank server.

I tried:

- the [slimv](/questions/tagged/slimv) Clear-REPL (`,-`) command:

  This only appears to clear the screen (buffer).
- CL-USER> `(swank:restart-server)` (from the REPL buffer):

  The server restarts but it still remembers my old `defun` and other defines.
- CL-USER> `(slime-restart-inferior-lisp)` and `(slimv-restart-inferior-lisp)

  Both are undefined.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There are possibilities to remove bindings for function and macro names, and you can get rid of whole packages.

Comment: @Daniel-Jour, edited the question trying clarify want I want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slimv author here. I added a new command 'Quit REPL' to slimv. This closes the lisp process running the swank server by calling `swank:quit-lisp`, then closes the REPL buffer. You can use this one followed by another 'Connect Server' command to restart the REPL. The default mapping for 'Quit REPL' is `<Leader>Q`, so you can restart the REPL by the `<Leader>Q<Leader>c` sequence.
Please see commits [44a50afc...](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/commit/44a50afc5bfed414821fdb479e5a1f00df867e72) on GitHub or [a8abdbbc...](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv/commits/a8abdbbc5a104c5a45ba5d11f2ddd84cbfa6dcc1) on BitBucket.

Answer (score 2):

`M-x slime-restart-inferior-lisp` will restart things from scratch.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that I'm using [tag:vim] with [tag:slimv] and not emacs with slime, so `M-x …` will not work.  I'll try to find how to input `slime-restart-inferior-lisp` into vim and i'll check the implementation of the slime emacs mode to see how `slime-restart-inferior-lisp` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This not solve directly your problem, but if you need to lost all your variables when restart, maybe working in a separate package should work for you.

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :my-separate-package (:use :cl :cl-user :swank))
#<PACKAGE "MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE">
CL-USER> (in-package :my-separate-package)
#<PACKAGE "MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE">
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> (defvar a "a")
A
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> a
"a"
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> (in-package :cl-user)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER> (in-package :my-separate-package)
#<PACKAGE "MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE">
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> a
"a"
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> (in-package :cl-user)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER> (delete-package :my-separate-package)
T
CL-USER> (defpackage :my-separate-package (:use :cl :cl-user :swank))
#<PACKAGE "MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE">
CL-USER> a
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE A {1004AD9AF3}>.
CL-USER> (in-package :my-separate-package)
#<PACKAGE "MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE">
MY-SEPARATE-PACKAGE> a
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE A {10055C6063}>.
```

Then you delete your environment and you do not have this variables, everytime you redifine the package